# Quotient ring of nilpotent ring doesn't have any nilpotents beside 0

Tags: ring-theory, nilpotence

How do I show that for the qoutient ring of a ring $R$ and an ideal $N=\{a\in R| a^{n}=0\}$, the only nilpotent elements in the qoutient is $0$?

But a logic question, isn't it not true, because N is in the qoutient ring and N is all the nilpotent elements?

Otherwise, let's take an item from the quotient and look when he is niplotent: $$\left(a+N\right)^n=N$$ 
$\left(a+N\right)^n=a^n+N=N$ that is true if and only if $a\in N$ or $a=0$, and that's why I asked the qeuestion, because $a$ in R (and in particular we can choose him from N and get the neutral cosset, N itself, so it seems to be that all the nilpotent items are in the quotient, isn't it?).

Comment: If $a^n\in N$, for some $n$, then $a^n$ is nilpotent, by definition of $N$. So $(a^n)^m=0$, for some $m$; therefore $a$ is nilpotent and $a+N=N$. Thus the only nilpotent element in $R/N$ is $0+N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x$ in $R/N$ such that $x^n=0$. Now $x=a+N$ for some $a\in R$, and so we know that $a^n\in N$, that is for some $m$ $a^{nm}=0$. In other words $a\in N$, so that $x=a+N=0$ in $R/N$.

Comment: First of all, as I understand $x^{n}$ cant be 0, because it is a cosset and not a number. So the "0" cosset is N, as I understand. I dont understand from what you wrote why should be $a^{n}\in N$ . Very confusing.

Comment: $R/N$ is a ring, and it has a zero element, namely the coset $N$. So when I write $x^n=0$ I mean exactly $x^n=N$. For your second question: take $\alpha\in R$ and consider its coset $\alpha+N$ in $R/N$. What does it mean for $\alpha+N$ to be $0$ (that is $N$) in $R/N$? It means exactly $\alpha \in N$. In our case we have $a^n+N=N$, so $a^n\in N$.

Comment: Oh, now I understood it better, thank's.